# mysql syntax query .difference between having and where what is the difference betw

Tags: mysql

```
create table employee(empid int,empname varchar(20),salary int, month varchar(20));
select empid,sum(salary) as total from employee group by empid **where** total>25000;
```

Why can't we use `where` in this program? Why is having `key` the only accepted thing?

Comment: WHERE is for SELECT and HAVING is for GROUP. This is the definition of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify: `WHERE` is used **before** a `GROUP BY` clause to filter the rows. `HAVING` is used **after** a `GROUP BY` and can access the "result" of the `GROUP BY` statement. See the documentation on [the `HAVING` statement in `SELECT` statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> The `HAVING` clause, like the `WHERE` clause, specifies selection conditions. The `WHERE` clause specifies conditions on columns in the select list, but cannot refer to aggregate functions. The `HAVING` clause specifies conditions on groups, typically formed by the `GROUP BY` clause. The query result includes only groups satisfying the `HAVING` conditions. (If no `GROUP BY` is present, all rows implicitly form a single aggregate group.)

That's why you can't access `total` in your `sum(salary) as total` expression with the `WHERE` clause, but *can* access it with the `HAVING` clause, which is applied after the result of `sum(salary)` is calculated and the `GROUP BY` clause is applied.